# NullPointerException in my sorting method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I think my `rsort()` method should work right I always get an exception:

```
In Thread "main": java.lang.NullPointerExeception
    at IntQueue.get(IntQueue.java:47)
    at V5.main(V5.java:88)
```

Why am I getting this exception and how can I handle it?

#### IntQueue.java:

```
class IntQueue
{
    public int get()
    {
        int res = fyrsti.tala;              // <---- this is line 47 -----
        n--;
        if( fyrsti == sidasti )
            fyrsti = sidasti = null;
        else
            fyrsti = fyrsti.naest;
        return res;
    }

    static class Hlekkur
    {
        int tala;
        Hlekkur naest;
    }

    Hlekkur fyrsti;
    Hlekkur sidasti;
    int n;

    public IntQueue()
    {
        fyrsti = sidasti = null;
    }

    public int first()
    {
        return fyrsti.tala;
    }

    public void put( int i )
    {
        Hlekkur nyr = new Hlekkur();
        n++;
        nyr.tala = i;
        if( sidasti==null )
            fyrsti = sidasti = nyr;
        else
        {
            sidasti.naest = nyr;
            sidasti = nyr;
        }
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

#### V5.java:

```
public class V5
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        IntQueue q = new IntQueue();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i!= 10000; i++)
            q.put(rand.nextInt(1000));
        q = rsort(q);
        int last = q.get();                 // <---- this is line 88 -----
        while(q.count() != 0)
        {
            int x = q.get();
            if(x < last)
                System.out.println("Wrong");
            System.out.println("Right");
            last = x;
        }
    }

    public static IntQueue rsort(IntQueue q)
    {
        IntQueue [] r = new IntQueue[10]; 
        for(int i = 0; i!=10; i++)
            r[i] = new IntQueue();
        IntQueue q2 = q;
        int i = 0, v=1;
        while(i != 3)
        {
            while(q2.count() != 0)
            {
                int x = q.get();
                r[(x/v)%10].put(x);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j!=0; j++)
            {
                if(r[j].count() != 0)
                    q2.put(r[j].get());
                else
                    j++;
            }
            v *= 10;        
            i++;
        }
        return q2;
    }
}
```

<sub>[ed. note: reordered and compacted code to make relevant lines more visible]</sub>

Comment: Since the NPE occurs in IntQueue, it would be nice to have the source code for that class.

Comment: I've moved your code from your answer update into the question, where it should be.  Also made some heavy changes to the formatting.  Normally you should be posting small snippets of code which contains the error and other relevant parts.  By having a "wall of code", it's more likely to be negatively received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have exception in Java you have enough information in stack trace to localize what cause the problem.

**Your stacktrace**

```
In Thread "main": java.lang.NullPointerExeception
at IntQueue.get(IntQueue.java:47)
at V5.main(V5.java:88)
```

It means that in your main method in V5 class at 88 line you call method get (from IntQueue). This method get() in line 47 operate on null value and this cause NullPointerException

Often when you have exception the best way is to set breakpoint and check variables in debug mode. I recommend you setting breakpoint in 47 line in the IntQueue and then you will see what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this should be posted as a comment, not as an answer...

Comment: Neither am I the DV, but... It's not the answer - it's a question that leads to information that helps you derive the answer. The question specifically says "Can someone spot why?" not "Can someone spot where?". Sorry bud!

Comment: @glowcoder: the word "answer" what I used means exactly what you said - I haven't been detailed enough. I've added some hint to keep away downvoters

Comment: @smas: What they're saying is that what you said in this "answer" does not really answer the question given by endif.  You are merely asking for clarification to the question not very substantial, something that should have been a comment.  This is considered noise and seeing as you have the rep to be able to post comments, you should have known better.

Comment: mea culpa, I've changed my post

Answer (score 3):

The exceptiion happens on line 47 of `IntQueue`. And as a [`NullPointerException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), it can be due to the following reasons:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a null object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

My guess (without seeing the code of `IntQueue` is that it's because you are trying to autounbox an `Integer` to `int`, but the `Integer` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what IntQueue looks like. Apparently you're calling the `get` method from `IntQueue` from line 88 of V5.java, and that method is failing at line 47 of IntQueue.java. That could be due to passing a bad argument to the method, or setting up the `IntQueue` incorrectly, or anything like that. It's pretty hard to tell without seeing the source to `IntQueue` and not knowing which is line 88 of V5.java. (The code you've posted doesn't *have* 88 lines.)

I suggest you look at line 47 of IntQueue.java and examine what it's trying to dereference, and line 88 of V5.java to see what's calling it. Then you should be able to work out where the bug is.